# Keep getting thread 1, can't rotate a ball in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I have tried many ways of writing the code to get it to rotate, but keep getting threads.

First way:

```
import UIKit 
import SpriteKit

class PlayScene: SKScene {
    let hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero.png")
    let groundSpeed = 5

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // code
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        //rotate the hero (in shape of a ball)

        let rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(5, duration: 1)
        let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateAction)
        hero.runAction(repeatAction)
    }
}
```

Second way:

```
var degreeRotation = CDouble(self.groundSpeed) * M_PI / 180
//rotate the hero
self.hero.zRotation -= CGFloat(degreeRotation)
```

I have tried making an Int extension for degree to radians translation (like someone already suggested on Stackoverflow) but for some reason none of them worked. I am very new to Swift and I don't know what to try anymore, so if you can help me, please do.

Comment: What does "I keep getting threads" mean? If there is an error message then please copy and paste the entire error message.

Comment: Also, you do not use the `update` method to run actions. This is probably the cause of your problem. Actions execute themselves. You should not place them in the update method.

Comment: The problem is that I don't get an error message, just Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1..   I am following a youtube tutorial where the code is constructed like this: https://github.com/skipallmighty/Skiptaculous/blob/master/Skiptaculous/PlayScene.swift, so I didn't know I shouldn't do that. Thank you for pointing that out. I assume I should use the NSTimer and ScheduleWithInterval if not the update method?

Comment: See my answer below. SKAction executes itself. You do not need to update with any timers. You don't need update method or NSTimer or scheduleWithInterval. You tell it what to do and execute the action. You are getting that breakpoint because your app is crashing and the only entry point it has is main.m. You need to add an exception breakpoint to see where it is crashing.

Comment: The code you are linking to does not use SKAction. You should never copy and paste code without understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this...

```
import UIKit 
import SpriteKit

class PlayScene: SKScene {
    let hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero.png")
    let groundSpeed = 5

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // code to add the hero sprite to the view.
        // if the sprite is not added to the view then nothing will happen with actions.
        // M_PI = half a turn. Work in radians, not degrees.
        let rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle((CGFloat)M_PI, duration: (NSTimeInterval)1)
        let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateAction)
        hero.runAction(repeatAction)
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error: cannot invoke 'rotateByAngle' with an argument list of type '(Double, duration Int)'

Comment: @Uros1234 Edited. You need to start looking at the documentation. It really is the best way to learn about swift and SpriteKit. Just search Google for SKAction. It will link to the docs.

Comment: It works now, thank you. I know I should, I just started learning it and thought I would first just follow along some app making tutorials to get the basic idea how things work.